# my iOS SwiftUI project doesn't play sounds with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, avaudioplayer

I have a stupid issue but for some reason I can't resolve it. I try to play sound with AVAudioPlayer but can't hear anything. There are no errors, but still my app is silent. Its built with SwiftUI. This is a piece of code:

```
struct SoundsListView: View {
    
   var body: some View {
        List(Helpers.shared.sounds, id:\.self) { item in
            Text(item)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                var soundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
                guard let audioFile: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Analog watch", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
                do {
                    soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFile)
                    print(soundPlayer)
                    guard let player = soundPlayer else { return }
                   player.play()
                } catch let error {
                    print("Cannot play sound")
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "play")
            } //: BUTTON
        }
    }
}
```

There are no errors, also sound files have target membership set.
(What is strange it's that the same piece of code works with my older project, but written in Swift + Storyboards)

There is no sound generated neither in simulator nor hardware device. Silent mode is off, volume set to max.
I have no idea what's wrong here.

BTW: This app sends notifications to user and sound is OK. But not in this piece of code

Comment: Hi, Do any of the print commands get called? Also, could you see if your view is being re-rendered when you press the button?

Answer (score 5):

Your `AVAudioPlayer` only exists in the scope of your button action, so it’s deallocated before the sound can play. You need to save it somewhere… I think you could declare it in `SoundsListView` as a `@State var`, but it may be better to refactor it out of the SwiftUI view entirely.

EDIT: You probably also need to set your AVAudioSession, which lets you change playback category and control how your audio interacts with other audio e.g. music playback.

Example:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: [.mixWithOthers])
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I just moved it separate file, but it didnt help at all. No errors again. Also I tried to print "player" variable AFTER player.play() and I got in the console:   Optional(<AVAudioPlayer: 0x2811b1a60>). Still don't know what to do

Comment: Update:  Sound works with earphones connected to iphone. Why is that? I moved the whole player to separate class. But how to switch to speaker?

Comment: You probably have the ring/silent switch on, which mutes speaker audio by default. Check out AVAudioSession, which lets you change playback category and control how your audio interacts with other audio e.g. music playback.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. Devices have silent off (I tried simulator, iPhone, iPad). Also as I said, at the same time I run my old app written with storyboards and it was working ok. Thanks for tips again

Answer (score 1):

For me the audio would only work sometimes.  I had to ensure that when I declared my audio player in the SwiftUI View, it was an @State object.  After I added @State before my property it played every time!  I am importing AVKit on a separate file where I have my audio play functions... something like I have pasted below.  Lmk if you need more clarification.

```
//In my View I have something like this at the top 

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var vm = PlayViewModel()   

//When I want some audio to play I call it like this...                      vm.play(fileNamed: "blip")
//And the rest of my SwiftUI code below

}
```

//And then this is what I have setup in a separate Swift file.

import AVKit

```
class PlayViewModel {
    
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    
    
    func play(fileNamed:String) {
        let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileNamed, ofType: "wav")
        
        audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay() //maybe not needed?  idk

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```